# Origem da expressão "cheque careca"?

Tags: expressões, origem

Qual é a origem da expressão *cheque careca*?

Não consegui encontrar no google e como a expressão é muito comum achei que vale a pena perguntar aqui.

**EDIT:** A primeira resposta que a pergunta recebeu clarificou o sentido da expressão (que eu nunca tinha percebido). No caso de alguém saber, ou descobrir, a origem histórica da expressão agradeço que contribuam essa informação aqui.

Comment: Cheque careca, sinônimo de cheque sem fundos?

Comment: Exatamente, @Peixoto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diz-se "careca" do cheque que não tem cobertura.

---

Um careca tem a cabeça descoberta, não tem [cobertura](https://dicionario.priberam.org/cobertura):

> 2. O que serve para cobrir.

Então, chama-se careca a um cheque que não tenha [cobertura](https://dicionario.priberam.org/cobertura):

> 8. Dinheiro que permite pagar um documento de cobrança ou uma operação (ex.: cheque sem cobertura). = PROVISÃO

---

"cobertura", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2020, https://dicionario.priberam.org/cobertura [consultado em 21-01-2020].

Comment: Ou será que isto é obvio para ti, e queres a origem histórica? Primeiro uso, etc?

Comment: Sim, por acaso eu gostava de saber o primeiro uso, era a minha intenção quando fiz a pergunta (talvez tenha uma história engraçada que valha a pena) Mas, a maneira como explicaste o sentido também foi muito boa pois eu não tinha associado o "careca" ao "sem cobertura" e assim faz todo o sentido :)

Comment: Também podes perfeitamente editar a pergunta para clarificar que não querias perceber "de como" vem a expressão, mas "de quando" vem a expressão. E eu atiro esta resposta ao galheiro. :) Não me incomoda nadinha.

Comment: Em pt-BR temos várias denominações populares para o cheque sem fundos.  Cheque bomerangue (volta sempre para a sua mão), cheque frio, cheque voador, cheque borracha, cheque bom filho (a casa torna), cheque cowboy (ganha quem sacar primeiro), cheque procissão (sai, dá a volta no quarteirão e retorna), etc.

Comment: @Centaurus a criatividade Brasileira nestes casos é do melhor :)

Comment: @ANeves deixa ficar a resposta, eu já disse que gostei dela. Não era a minha ideia inicial, mas acabou por ser uma surpresa agradável. Aprecio a qualidade da reposta e o esforço que fizeste.